# DomDocument check if website has responsive design

Tags: php, laravel, domdocument, responsive

The last thing i need to do for my scan is: checking if the website that i'm scanning is responsive.

I've tried to check via `if($node->getAttribute('class')=='row') {`but this doesn't work. Is there some way i can check if the website is responsive?

```
$responsive = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
```

I'm using **Laravel 5.4 and DomDocument**.

```
foreach ($responsive as $node) {
  if($node->getAttribute('class')=='row') {
   echo "Is responsive";
   }
}
```

I'm checking 'row' because a lot of people use **Bootstrap or Foundation** If you know a way that i can check with media queries, please let me know ^^,

Thanks,

Itvba

Comment: Are you trying to check whether it is running on a mobile or tablet?

Comment: No, i just want to check if the website is fully responsive. On every screen.

Comment: What is `$responsive`? What is `$node`?

Comment: @u_mulder, i've added it into my post

Comment: I don't see. What will you do if there's `class="row otherClass"`?